# Do you get battlepoint when leaving a match early?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

We had a discussion with a colleague yesterday. He left a squad game after he died and went to lobby and played a single game while we were still playing the squad game. He said he will get battle points from the squad after we are finished, we said he will get no battle points for the match because he left to lobby.

We could not prove this, because he did not keep track his battle points and had no time for another match to test this. A quick google search today gave me no clear result. Will you still receive battle points for a match in duo or squad if you leave to lobby while teammates are still playing?

(According to google there could be a difference if you just leave to lobby while alive or only after death, but there were different opinions in the thread I found).

Also it would be interesting to know if there is any difference if you leave to lobby or completely leave the game?

Answer (score 3):

Upon death in a team game, your points aren't shown to you until the rest of your team is either killed off or wins.  I played some duo games with my friend and at one point I was killed, and it didn't show them.  My teammate was still in the game at that point I backed out to the lobby.  Again, I tracked my BP, and it showed that after quitting to lobby, I was given points (I don't know how much, but it appears I only got position points since I didn't shoot or kill anyone).

In a Solo match I tested, I landed fast and got a kill quickly and exited to lobby.  Prior to the game, my BP total was 9,656.  After getting my kill and exiting to the lobby, it was 9,726.  I got 40 points for the kill (20 for damage, 20 for the kill) and apparently an additional 30 points (I assume for the position that I made it to).  I see no reason why this wouldn't work the same way for a team game mode.  This leads me to believe that your BP is granted immediately upon an action being performed (position change, damaging someone, and getting a kill).

Comment: In regard to first paragraph, in team games you will get different amounts of BP depending on how well your teammates do. For example if you are Duo and you die as soon as you land then leave, but your teammates goes on to place first how much BP do you get? If you stay in you would get 400BP is this the same even if you leave early?

Comment: @Malco when you die in team games and you still have teammates left, the screen shows you how much BP you earned for that match.  I believe at that point, it cannot change, even if your team goes on and win.  I believe the position points is included in this as well.

Comment: do you play with your own squad or with randoms? Because what you are describing is different from my experience playing with friends...

Comment: @Malco with my own friends.  I could be wrong, but I could have swore when you die in a team game it shows your points earned.  Now that I think about it, it might display your points when the rest of your team dies... If that is the case, I assume the position points will be whatever the rest of your team made it to as you've said.  Watching various videos seems to reveal that this is the case.  I'll see if I can test this with my friends later.

Comment: @ Timmy Np, I wasn't entirely confident in what I am remembering either, usually you have other things on your mind when you have just died :P. looking forward to the edit after you do your testing.

Comment: I only know, if you die early and watch your teammates till end you get same position Points like the best Player in your team(at least that is shown in result screen). Still nor clear what exactly happens when you leave to lobby or close game early, maybe you get only position points you had at that moment. Maybe you can test more and update your answer, at the moment there are to much open questions to accept that answer

Comment: If that can help, I just looked up a match I had yesterday on OP.GG, where all my teammates died early and I went on to get 2nd place. My teammate has it registered as finished 22nd in the same match. So I guess the Team Placement BP counted is more like if your team was eliminated before you. So if you died when there were still 21 teams alive, you finish 22nd, even if one of your teammates carried on. He DCed, so I don't know if the position is saved when you DC or if you stay with the teammate you will get a higher position on OP.GG